# Android Auto desktop-head-unit.exe fails to start on Windows 7

Tags: android, windows, adb, android-auto

I have followed [Running DHU Guide](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/08/announcing-android-auto-desktop-head.html) on Windows 7 machine. but when I start desktop-head-unit.exe, I get error saying "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."